# Aurelia customAttribute to toggle input edit

Tags: aurelia

I need some help in figuring out the best way to create a `customAttribute` that will allow for an easy edit-toggle. Here is what I'm looking for:

```
<tr toggle-edit>
  <td edit-hide>${model.name}</td>
  <td edit-show><input type="text" value.bind="model.name"></td>
  <td><button edit-trigger>Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

So basically I want a `customAttribute` named `toggleEdit` that will look for `edit-trigger` attribute and add an event listener to it that will toogle a variable true/false and depending on it will either show or hide the elements that have `edit-hide` / `edit-show`.

I'd prefer to not travers the `DOM` inside the `element` to find these attributes as it feels jQuerish, is this achievable?

I want to have a customAttribute like this because I have at least 10 elements that will use an edit button and having a variable for each one of them and then use `if.bind` seems like a bad idea. I could always do inside of the template itself through `click.delegate="myShowVar = !myShowVar"` but as far as I know puting logic inside html is a bad practice (coming from an angular background).

I would add a plunker/codepen but because of the whole compilation and libraries dependencies this does not seem like an easy task.

Many thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the plunkr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my `<tr></tr>` turned out to be a 14 line code (with some animation on toggling) I decided it was best to create a `customElement` out of it. The problem I ran on was that `customElement`s don't really work as table elements (similar as in other frameworks). The soultion to this is to use a `as-element` attribute.

Inside of the `customElement` I used `contenteditable` which is actually a better solution than using `if.bind` since swapping between `input` and a `div` produces a jumping effect because of the difference in styles (which of course could be circumnavigated by applying certain style to them but `contenteditable` works out-of-the-box).

This is more or less what I created (`parent.html`):

```
<tr as-element="my-custom-row"
    title="My first row"
    is-editable="true"
    model.two-way="myModel.name"
    value-changed-callback.call="updateModel(myModel)">
</tr>
```

And inside `my-custom-row.html`:

```
<template>
    <td>${title & oneTime}</td>
    <td>
        <div contenteditable.one-way="editingEnabled ? 'true' : 'false'"
             blur.trigger="valueChanged(model)"
             textcontent.two-way="model">
        </div>
        <div class="my-class" class.one-way="editingEnabled ? 'my-class--active' : ''"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="edit-icon"
            click.delegate="editingEnabled = !editingEnabled"
            if.one-time="isEditable">
        </span>
    </td>
</template>
```

This way I don't have to create a variable for each edit since `editingEnabled` is unique to each `customElement`.

As I side note, I think it's better to be more explicit and to use `one-way`/`two-way`/`one-time` instead of `bind` since it's clear what is happening.

I will also provide the corresponding js for a full answer(`my-custom-row.js`):

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyCustomRow {
    @bindable model;
    @bindable title;
    @bindable isEditable;
    @bindable valueChangedCallback;

    constructor() {}

    valueChanged(modelValue) {
        this.valueChangedCallback({ modelValue })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Use the *contenteditable* attribute**

I recommend against trying to have a custom attribute automagically handling this for you. You'll probably run into more problems than you'll solve this way. Instead, I recommend that you create an editable property in your view model and bind to it.

The contenteditable attribute is a standard HTML attribute that allows for editing the content of HTML elements, such as DIVs, and is supported out of the box with Aurelia. I recommend leveraging it if it will meet your needs. Here's how:

**table.html**

```
<td contenteditable.bind="editable"></td>
<td><button click.delegate="editable = !editable"></td>
```

Full running gist here: https://gist.run/?id=c4e716f21f4f9c15a9346cfacbdae74b

Comment: Thanks for the response. `contenteditable` is similar to if.bind in the sense that I need to have a variable for each `td` which is what I'm trying to avoid. Maybe it's not so bad to create it only inside the html and I will probably settle on this if I don't find a better solution. Btw. I love the aurelia experience so far =)

Comment: Using `if.bind` to show / hide an editable and static elements is also an excellent solution, and follows this basic structure as well.

Comment: I've settled on contenteditable as for now and decided to create a customElement. The problem is that customElements don't really work inside tables [link](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/112). I will post a full response to this question with my final result as soon as I deal with the above problem.